# Quick way to obtain parts of matrix satisying a condition with Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, vectorization

I would need a **fast** way to fetch parts in a matrix and stack them up in a new matrix. Suppose I had a matrix like this:

M=

```
 1    45     4
 1    91    15
 2    34    89
 3    89     9
 3    96    99
```

Now I want to e.g. get all the elements in the last two columns s.t. the left column has values [1; 3], i.e. the output should look like this:

```
 45     4
 91    15
 89     9
 96    99
```

To get e.g. the part corresponding to 1's on the first column, I could do

```
M(M(:,1) == 1,2:end),
```

and I could use an 'or' logical to get parts corresponding to [1;3], but in the real case I would have a long vector of integers... is there a vectorized way of doing this?

I think a for loop might be quite fast too, but the parts of the matrix will be of different sizes, and stacking them up quickly might be difficult...

Comment: check the `ismember()` function. Define yourself a array containing your corresponding values (e.g. [1,3]). THen check rather the element in M is member of that vector.

Comment: Thanks for the tip The Minion, it actually works! Will post my own answer below too...

Comment: Typically how many integers would you be comparing against? If it's just two like `[1 3]`, using `M(:,1) == 1 | M(:,1) == 3` could be faster than `bsxfun` solution I think, maybe not a convenient one though.

Comment: Divakar: many integers...

Comment: If any solution posted here has satisfied to the needs of the question, consider accepting it, so that `SO` could consider this as a "closed case" and people in similar needs are helped the rightest way.

Comment: Meant to do some benchmarks, but haven't had time... anyway, solution accepted!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See if this is fast enough for you -

```
int_arr = [1 3]; %// array of integers to select the rows
M(any(bsxfun(@eq,M(:,1),int_arr),2),2:end)
```

Or

```
int_arr = [1;3]; %// array of integers to select the rows
M(any(bsxfun(@eq,M(:,1)',int_arr)),2:end)
```

Comment: What is the use of `any` in this case? How do you select the rows? As far as I can see, the output of `any` is used to select the rows of `M` in this instance and [any()](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/any.html) will return 0 or 1 so how do you get the correct rows? This selects the row number 0 or 1 if I have understood the code correctly.

Comment: @kkuilla `bsxfun` output with `@eq` is a binary matrix with `ones` at places where the equality condition between the first column of M is met against `1` and `3`. The use of `any` here is like `OR` to select rows corresponding to when column 1 has `1` OR `3`. Hope this will make sense! :)

Comment: I disagree with the fact that `any()` returns row numbers but hey... your answer works. :-) +1

Comment: @kkuilla It doesn't return row number, it returns a logical array of "valid rows" after "ORing" with `any`. This logical array is used to index into those valid rows, thus using `logical indexing`. Use of `any` here is just `ORing`, that's all.

Comment: I get the gist but I should proably dissect your answer a bit more to see how it actually comes together...

Comment: @kkuilla Exactly! If you run it piece by piece, hopefully everything would be clear! :) Appreciate the up-vote! ;)

Answer (score 3):

Found an answer based on a suggestion by The Minion... so first find the rows that satisfy the condition:

```
idx = ismember(testmat(:,1),[1 3])

ans =

 1
 1
 0
 1
 1
```

Now replace the first column:

```
M(:,1) = idx

M=
 1    45     4
 1    91    15
 0    34    89
 1    89     9
 1    96    99
```

... and then just do

```
M(M(:,1)==1,2:end).
```

I haven't compared the speed to Divakar's solution above, since I'm in a hurry, but let's see which one is faster! ;)

Comment: Could you add the link to the post you have based this on, please?

Comment: Or indeed just use `m(ismember(m(:,1),[1,3]),2:end)`

Comment: @MikeLimaOscar thats what i was trying to get to. Just that i would recommend to change `[1 3]` to an array which you define somewhere else. Easier to modify then.

Comment: +1, although the solution with `bsxfun` may be faster

Comment: Just curious if you were able to get some runtime benchmarks on the presented solutions.